# Omit specific subsection from table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart

Is it possible to omit a single specific subsection from the table of contents, while keeping it numbered as usual within the main body, and keeping other subsections listed?

(I am using the `amsart` class.)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Just curious...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code provides the an `\addsubsection` macro that works similar to `\subsection` (starred version, optional argument) that uses the `\qrr@gobblenexttocentry` macro to suppress the content that gets written to the `.toc` file.

When the [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package is used this line consists of five parameters, hence the `\ifcsname` check.

This won’t work if between the to-be-hidden subsection and its predecessor is not a single character. (But why would one do this?)

#### Reference

- [AMS FAQ: How can I omit or change a heading in the table of contents?](http://www.ams.org/faq?faq_id=238)

### Code

```
\documentclass{amsart}

%\usepackage{hyperref}% works with or without hyperref

\makeatletter
\ifcsname phantomsection\endcsname
    \newcommand*{\qrr@gobblenexttocentry}[5]{}
\else
    \newcommand*{\qrr@gobblenexttocentry}[4]{}
\fi
\newcommand*{\addsubsection}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\qrr@gobblenexttocentry}%
    \subsection}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{section name}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{I'm here.}
\lipsum[1]
\addsubsection{I'm gone.}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{I'm there.}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the following code, whatever is put between `\ignorethis...\endignorethis` is ignored, and `\TOCstop` with `\TOCstart` simply write these two commands into the `.toc` file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\protected\def\ignorethis#1\endignorethis{}
\let\endignorethis\relax
\def\TOCstop{\addtocontents{toc}{\ignorethis}}
\def\TOCstart{\addtocontents{toc}{\endignorethis}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{FOO}
\subsection{BAR}
\TOCstop
\subsection{BAZ}
\TOCstart
\subsection{BAR}

\end{document}
```