# Amsart and starred subsections

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart

how can I prevent starred subsections \subsection*{...} from being shown in the TOC of an amsart?

Thanks in advance!

Minimal Example (Mind: You have to compile it at least twice for the starred subsection to show up)

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Eins}
    \subsection{Einseins}
    \subsection*{Einszwei}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100510/omit-specific-subsection-from-table-of-contents